# Changing the color of Tkinter canvas after set period of time

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm trying to set a Tkinter canvas to red/green for one second, then back to white afterward. However, despite the fact that the code setting the canvas to red/green precedes the code reverting back to white, the window doesn't reflect the initial color change. I understand that by calling .after, the program freezes until the specified duration is over, but I don't understand why it doesn't change to red or green before freezing.

```
            if is_correct:
                self.canvas.config(bg="green")
            else:
                self.canvas.config(bg="red")
            self.window.after(1000, self.canvas.config(bg="white"))
```

Comment: lambda: self.canvas.config(bg="white")), try

Answer (score 1):

Refer to this simple program.

```
from tkinter import *
root=Tk()
def change_bg():
    canvas.config(bg="red")
    root.after(1000,lambda: canvas.config(bg="white"))
canvas=Canvas(root,bg="white")
canvas.pack()
root.after(1000,change_bg)

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from tkinter import *
import time


def change_color():
    can.config(bg="red")
    can.update()
    change_color2()


def change_color2():
    time.sleep(1)
    can.config(bg="white")


root = Tk()
root.geometry("500x500")
can = Canvas(root, bg="white", height=450, width=500)
can.pack()
Button(root, text="Change color for 1 sec", command=change_color).pack()

root.mainloop()
```

You can refer to this code